# Prove that $\frac{\varphi(x)}{x}$ is increasing where $\varphi$ is star-shaped

Tags: analysis

Let $\varphi$ be a star-shaped function i.e. $\varphi (\alpha x)\leq \alpha \varphi (x)$ for all $\alpha \in [0,1]$. Prove that $\dfrac{\varphi (x)}{x}$ is increasing in $x>0$.

Comment: Do you find either of the answers below acceptable? If so, you should accept one. If not, could you let us know what it is you are yet to understand?

Comment: @Michael Albanese Now his choice is clear :)

Answer (score 4):

Let $x, y \in (0, \infty)$ with $x \leq y$. Then $x = \alpha y\ $ where $\alpha = \dfrac{x}{y} \in (0, 1]$.

Then

$$\frac{\varphi(x)}{x} = \frac{\varphi(\alpha y)}{\alpha y} \leq \frac{\alpha\varphi(y)}{\alpha y} = \frac{\varphi(y)}{y}.$$

Therefore the function $\dfrac{\varphi(x)}{x}$ is increasing on $(0, \infty)$.